# Goのデータベース接続はどこに書けばいいのでしょうか。

Tags: go, postgresql

今GoでWebAPIを作成しているのですが、以下の構成の場合、handlers/inqueryHandlers.goやhandlers/proxyHandlers.go内でデータベースからデータを取得してレスポンスを返すので、handlersパッケージないでデータベースを初期化しようと考えたのですが、handlersパッケージないで`_"github.com/lib/pq"`をするとmainまたはtestパッケージ以外ではしないべきとlintに引っかかります。この場合どこでデータベースを初期化すればいいのでしょうか?  データベースはpostgresqlです。

```html
├── handlers
│   ├── inqueryHandlers.go
│   └── proxyHandlers.go
├── loger.go
├── main.go
├── model
│   └── inquery.go
├── router.go
└── routes.go
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`golint`がメッセージを出す理由については、作者がこのようにコメントしています。

https://github.com/golang/lint/issues/79#issuecomment-57747891

> Because it makes it impossible to use such a package with a different
>   dependency (e.g. a different MySQL driver), and slows down the build
>   because the program must be built from the bottom up. Underscore
>   imports should normally be in the main package, or you should add a
>   comment explaining why the package needs to do the underscore import.

アンダースコアで始まるimportは普通グローバルな状態に副作用を及ぼしますから、下層のパッケージで好き勝手に行うとトラブルのもとになります。ですから、通常は`main`に書いたほうが良いということになります。

今回の場合も`main`に書けば問題はないと思います。

ちなみに`golint`は

> a blank import should be only in a main or test package, or have a comment justifying it

と言っていますので、コメントを書けば`main` `test`以外でも黙ります。

```
import (
    // PostgreSQL driver
    _ "github.com/lib/pq"
)
```

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。もしmainパッケージのmain.goでデータベースを初期化した場合handlersパッケージからもアクセスできるのでしょうか。

Comment: それともmainパッケージでインポートしておけば、他のパッケージでもインポートしたものを使えるということですか。

Comment: プログラム内のどこか一箇所でimportすればパッケージに関係なくドライバが利用可能になります。

Comment: main.goに書くことで解決できました! ありがとうございます!!